# how to use hero twice with the same tag in the same screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 horizontal lists, list A (new products) and list B (most selling), in one screen. Each product of list A can also be in list B. This is briefly the product widget.

```
Column(
      children: [
        Hero(
          tag: product.id,
          child: Image.asset('images/product.jpg'),
        ),
        Text(${product.name)
      ],
    );
```

suppose that a product is in list A and list B, and I want to use hero widget, how to do so? because I tried and it gave me an error

```
There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: A `Hero` widget is for providing transition animations between what would otherwise be two different widgets on two different screens. You can't have two `Hero` widgets with the same key on the same screen visible at the same time, and I'm not sure why you would want to.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood completely what you are asking but as looking at the error I can only suggest you to give your Hero tag a value as product.name which will resolve your error.
Basically you can't apply same tag name to every list items with hero widget as it should be unique, I have also faced the same error and I resolved it by giving tag value as image-name.

Comment: yup each product has a unique id, but what I want is to have the same product in two different lists

Comment: @AliAlqallaf In that case you can append you tag value product.name  with _list1 for first ListView and _list2 for second or any additional string you may want. This might not  be the  answer you are looking for but this may resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can append "new" and "most_selling" to your tags, this way you can have the same item in both lists with 2 different tags

i.e
List A (item 1):

```
Hero(
   tag: "item_1_new",
   child: //
),
```

List B (item 1):

```
Hero(
   tag: "item_1_most_selling",
   child: //
),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to give widgets hero animation without navigation, i think this package can help you :
https://pub.dev/packages/local_hero